# "Fetch API cannot load" error on custom schema

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, ubuntu, fetch-api

I have a local file with this link:

```
<a href="vscode:/path/to/some/file" onclick="event.preventDefault();fetch('vscode:/path/to/some/file')" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">bar</a>
```

When I click on it I get the following in the console:

```
Fetch API cannot load vscode:/path/to/some/file. URL scheme "vscode" is not supported.
```

When I click the link in the error message, vscode opens fine.

So my guess is that this has to do with using `fetch`. How can I make it work? Specifically, using 'fetch' is not a must. I just have an application (chrome instance running in its own window) and handling the anchor as a regular link opens a new window just to run the protocol handler, which is annoying.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and latest Chrome. The Chrome instance is launched with `-disable-site-isolation-trials --disable-web-security` and a separate user-data-dir